# Finding CDF of the distance from point $T$ to closest diagonal of rectangle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A rectangle of dimensions $24\times 10$ is given. A point $T$ is chosen randomly. Find CDF of random variable $X$ that represents distance from point $T$ to closest diagonal of rectangle.

$5$ is the maximum distance from any point to diagonal.

$F_X(t)=  0, t\leq0 $

$F_X(t)=  ?, 0<t\leq5 $ I am not sure how to solve this part...

$F_X(t)=  1, t>5 $

Comment: In short: you need locus of points where one (pre-selected, certain) of diagonals is closer than another. Consider integration of probability of hitting a certain point over the locus and change the variables so one variable becomes the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition the rectangle into $8$ congruent right triangles, as shown below.

[image]

A randomly chosen point in the rectangle is equally likely to be in any of the $8$ triangles, and by symmetry, the distribution of $X$ is the same in each triangle, so we can assume the value of $X$ is based on a randomly chosen point from the lower left corner right triangle, with larger image shown below.

[image]

Since for the big right triangle, the area $K$ is given by $K=\frac{1}{2}{\,\cdot\,}12{\,\cdot\,}5=30$, and the length of the hypotenuse is $13$, the length $h$ of the altitude to the hypotenuse is given by $h={\large{\frac{60}{13}}}\approx 4.6$.

For any point in the big right triangle, the distance $d$ to the hypotenuse is in the interval $[0,h]$.

Fixing $d\in [0,h]$, the trapezoidal region above the smaller right triangle is the set of points in the big right triangle whose distance to the hypotenuse is at most $d$.

Let $k$ be the area of the smaller right triangle.$\;$Then by similarity, we get
$$
\frac{k}{K}=\Bigl(\frac{h-d}{h}\Bigl)^2
$$
hence
$$
P(X\le d)=\frac{K-k}{K}=1-\frac{k}{K}=1-\Bigl(\frac{h-d}{h}\Bigr)^2
$$
so
$$
F_X(d)
=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\;\,d < 0\\[4pt]
1-\Bigl({\Large{\frac{h-d}{h}}}\Bigr)^2&\text{if}\;\,0\le d\le h\\[4pt]
1&\text{if}\;\,d > h\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $h={\large{\frac{60}{13}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

First we find locus of points where one (pre-selected, certain) of diagonals is closer than another. Then we consider integration of probability of hitting a certain point over the locus and change the variables so one variable becomes the distance. Then multiply by $2$ by symmetry.

---

Let $-12\le x\le 12,\,-5\le y\le 5$ be the rectangle and $12y\pm 5x=0$ be the diagonals.
The distance from point $(x,y)$ to a line $Ax+By+C=0$ is known to be
$$\frac{|Ax+By+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}.$$
Let's find when one of the diagonals (say $12y-5x=0$) is closer than another:
$$\frac{|12y-5x|}{13}<\frac{|12y+5x|}{13}$$
$$|12y-5x|<|12y+5x|$$
$$(12y-5x)^2<(12y+5x)^2$$
$$144y^2-120xy+25x^2<144y^2+120xy+25x^2$$
$$xy>0$$
so it's I ($x,y>0$) and III ($x,y<0$) quadrants.

Now consider $\displaystyle \iint\limits_{-12\le x\le 12\\-5\le y\le 5}f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=1$ where $f(x,y)$ is the probability density function. As we're given an uniform (equiprobable) distribution of points over the rectangle $f(x,y)=c$ const, then
$$24\cdot 10\cdot c=1$$
$$f(x,y)=c=\frac{1}{240}.$$
Now let's change the variables. We consider only I quadrant ($x,y>0$) as the III quadrant has the same situation by symmetry. Then we multiply by $2$. Let $t$ be the distance from $(x,y)$ to $12y-5x=0$
$$t=\frac{|12y-5x|}{13}$$
The absolute value is inconvinient here, then we consider only $12y-5x\ge 0$ to get rid of it (and then multiply by $2$ by symmetry, yes)).
$$t=\frac{12}{13}y-\frac{5}{13}x$$
Let's form the other variable $s$ so that the transformation matrix becomes rotation matrix and we will be not involved into computation of Jacobian (it will be $=1$).
$$
\begin{pmatrix}t\\s
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{5}{13}&\frac{12}{13}\\
-\frac{12}{13}&-\frac{5}{13}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y
\end{pmatrix}$$
And the domain of integration $0\le y\le 5,\,0\le x\le 12,\,12y-5x\ge 0$ becomes $0\le \frac{12}{13}t-\frac{5}{13}s\le 5$,
$0\le -\frac{5}{13}t-\frac{12}{13}s\le 12$,
$13t\ge 0$ so the integral becomes
$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{60}{13}}
\int\limits_{\frac{12}{5}t-13}^{-\frac{5}{12}t}\frac{1}{240}
\,\mathrm{d}s
\,\mathrm{d}t=
\frac{1}{240}
\int\limits_0^{\frac{60}{13}}
\left(13 - \frac{169}{60}t\right)
\,\mathrm{d}t$$
So $$F'(t)=8\cdot\frac{1}{240}\cdot \left(13 - \frac{169}{60}t\right)$$
$$F(t)=\frac{1}{30}\int\limits_0^t \left(13 - \frac{169}{60}v\right)\,\mathrm{d}v=-\frac{13}{1800} \left(\frac{13 t^2}{2} - 60 t\right)$$